# ¿Cómo eliminar parámetros de una URL con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo podría hacer para eliminar un parámetro de la URL y que quede lo demás?, por ejemplo, tengo varios parámetros:

```
www.ejemplo.com?ordering=t1&ordering=t2
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para eliminar el `ordering=t1` que quede solo el `ordering=t2`?

Comment: Si quieres que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, mira [ask] e incluye un [mcve] con lo que has intentado al momento. Cómo consejo podrías apoyarte con [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) y separar por `?` para obtener los query params, luego separarlos por `&` y quedarte con el elemento necesario para formar la nueva url con los elementos correctos.

Answer (score 0):

## Eliminar duplicados de los parámetros de la URL

Para dejar el último en caso de duplicados se puede hacer esto:

```js
var parametrosUrl = `?ordering=t1&ordering=t2`;
var o = new URLSearchParams(parametrosUrl);
console.log(o.entries()); // o tiene { [ 'ordering', 't1' ], [ 'ordering', 't2' ] }
var m = new Map(o);
console.log(m); // m eliminó los duplicados, tiene { 'ordering' => 't2' }
var ns = new URLSearchParams(m);
console.log(ns.toString()) // ns.toString() tiene ordering=t2;
// cambio la URL:
window.history.replaceState(null,document.title,window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?' + ns.toString());
```

El window `replaceState` hace que no se refresque la página, si quieres refrescar esa línea hay que reemplazarla por:

```js
window.location=window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '?' + ns.toString();
```

### Eliminar parámetros con otros criterios

Si se desea eliminar parámetros con otros criterios se debe filtrar la lista de parámetros.

```js
var parametrosUrl = `?ordering=t1&ordering=t2`;
var o = new URLSearchParams(parametrosUrl);
console.log(o.entries()); // o tiene { [ 'ordering', 't1' ], [ 'ordering', 't2' ] }

var filtrado = [...o.entries()].filter(
    ([nombreParametro, valor])=>valor!='t2' // especificar el criterio de los que quedan acá!
);  

var m = new Map(filtrado); // el filtrado solo tiene los que los valores son distintos a t2
var ns = new URLSearchParams(m);
console.log(ns.toString()) // ns.toString() tiene ordering=t1;
```

### Aclaración

En el ejemplo tomamos `parametrosUrl` desde una constante, debería tomarse desde `window.location.search`

```js
var parametrosUrl = window.location.search
```